# Android Device configuration

Tags: android

How does android identifies the device configuration i.e. It has a touch screen, It doesn't have a hard key pad and so on... Is there any file from where these properties are loaded onto the device.

Answer (score 3):

This info can be accessed via [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) class.

Also your current Activity can get notified about [configuration change](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges).

Comment: I want to know who will populate the device details into this Configuration class.

Comment: `Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of the answer supplied by @Peter Knego.  To support what you feel is the correct answer, it would be more in line with the StackExchange philosophy to upvote Peter's answer and delete this one.